# unable to read self prepared csv file in google colab

Tags: python, csv, google-colaboratory

i tried make a `dataset` similar to iris `dataset` in `exel` (edited iris `csv` in `exel` and pasted my data in it). When I have tried to upload it in the google colab for reading using `pd.read_csv`(filename). It is throwing an error saying no columns to parse. Any help please?

Comment: My guess would be that you unintendedly changed the separator when saving the file in MS Excel. Open both the iris csv and your csv in an Editor (e.g. Notepad++) and have a look at the *real* content of your file to see if they are indeed alike.

Comment: Can you share a notebook that reproduces the problem? As described, your problem will be difficult to diagnose without knowing what you tried and what error you encountered.